# How to handle leap year in sql queries

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

My sample query:

```
declare @todaysdate datetime = getdate()


select * from foo f
WHERE f.completedt < (CAST(MONTH(@todaysdate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(DAY(@todaysdate) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(f.yr - 1 AS VARCHAR))
```

if you see i'm using `(yr - 1)` in where clause and this is throwing `date out of range` error for 2011, 2010, is there a good way to check leap year in query and use correct date?

Comment: Why aren't you using datadd or datediff in the sample query when that's what you have in the title? Looks like Dateadd would have done the trick as per Diego's answer... Is there something we are missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments in regards to the other answer how about something along these lines:

```
DECLARE @testyear INT
SET @testyear = 2011

SELECT DATEADD(year, @testyear-DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

The we are determining how much we want to add or subtract from the year bsaed on an input.

So in your case I think it would be:

```
select * from foo f inner join @yrtable y on f.yr = y.year
WHERE f.completedt < DATEADD(year, @testyear-DATEPART(YEAR, @todaysdate), @todaysdate)
```

(assuming I got my subtractions the right way around). :)

Comment: thank you,i tweaked your solution as per my requirement and it worked, this discussion helped me understand more than what i wanted.

Comment: Cool. Glad your understanding as well as having the right answer. [Insert proverb about teaching a man to fish here]

Answer (score 3):

try replacing yr - 1 by:

```
DATEADD(year,-1,yr )
```

Comment: my question was about leap year date, there is no 02/29/2011 date and i wanted to see if there is good way to check this condition.

Comment: @rs.: Diego's point is that if you do `SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())` that it works correctly today and gives 2011-02-28. The only reason you are having problems is because you are claiming in your code that there is a 2011-02-29 (assuming that f.completedt is a Datetime and thus your constructed string is being interpreted as a date).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, i'm not using dateadd because i may have  random years foo table and in yr table and i cannot use DateAdd(year -1, getdate())

Comment: @rs. - I agree with Chris and Diego. You are running into problems because you are using string manipulation to do date arithmetic. If you use the existing date functions, you'll find more power/flexibility and less problems. For example, you'll never generate an illegal date, or given a "start of month" you can get the "end of month" with `DATEADD(month, 1, start_of_month) - 1`. You really should *never* need to use strings...

Comment: @rs.: I've given an answer that uses DateAdd and works out how many years to add/subtract based on the target year. As Dems says you should never need string manipulation. Just work out what you need to do in terms of functions and you can almost always do it somehow (though it won't always look pretty. Also as a pointer on using strings as dates the iso format 2011-02-29 is a much better one to use because it is non-mabiguous. The american style dateformat is dependant on server settings when the day of month is 12 or less (ie your code may have different results on a UK server).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find if the year is leap year or not then this code can help you.

```
DECLARE 
   year integer := 2021; 
BEGIN 
   if((year mod(4) = 0) and (year mod(100) != 0) or (year mod(400) = 0)) then 
   dbms_output.put_line('Leap year');
   else
   dbms_output.put_line('not Leap year');
   end if;
   dbms_output.put_line('end');
END;
```

take the reference of it and do modifications required in your code

Comment: Although this answers the question of whether a year is a leap year, the actual problem is better answered by the accepted answer.